# What are the steps involved in porting an Arduino library?

Tags: library

I want to use the [Adafruit CC3000](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-cc3000-wifi) and its [Arduino libraries](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CC3000_Library) on another platform. In this case it's the Arduino pin compatible [PSOC4 Pioneer Kit](http://www.cypress.com/?rID=77780). This is an ARM Cortex M0 based platform.

My question is: How would I go about porting a library like this? What are the steps, key files etc?

One obvious issue is that PSOC Creator does not readily support C++.

One positive might be that the Arduino Due board is based on the Atmel SAM3X8E ARM Cortex-M3 CPU.

NOTE: If you think this question is off topic; please head over to [this question](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-about-arduino-compatible-micros-not-clones) on Arduino Meta to voice your opinion on whether questions on Arduino Compatible devices are appropriate for this list.

Comment: Are you asking how to port a Lib written in C++ to C?

Comment: Not really. Because I've seen that limited C++ support can be made to work in PSOC Creator. It's more the process of library porting I'm interested in. Particularly to an ARM Cortex based Arduino Compatible device.

Comment: ahh, Okay well then I am not quite sure how to do that, I thought you just wanted the library in C instead of C++

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did essentially the same thing with getting the Adafruit ST7735 library working in chipKIT. [I started a support thread here which can lead you through my process](http://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=42966).

I tackled it the same way I do general programming:
1-» Copy over Libraries, get it so your compiler can actually SEE them.
2-» Start trying to compile and then triage errors from the "top level" down:
3-» Look for stlib functions you recognize as should be working and fix those.
4-» Look for AVR specific code and comment those out. I normally also add my initials and a comment: `ckck - bitbanging SPI`, so I can search for these later.
Repeat 3 and 4 until it works or you quit. :)

Reach out to the forums for your target; they might have been there done that -- or like in my case, you introduce them to something that they want, so they dive in and help.